# OpenCL kernel doesn't seem to get global id "globally"

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl

I am trying to convert a program I did to OpenCL, but I am not familiar enough with it yet. Still, I am having trouble with one of my (three) kernels. It is basically a complex matrix vector multiplication, but I am writing it so to fit better with my needs.

The problem is, I can't get the kernel to work on GPU. I have simplified it to the most (2 lines), debugged on CPU, and it works perfectly ok on a CPU. But when it comes to GPU, everything screws up. I'm working on a MacBook Pro, and on a NVIDIA GeForce 650M I get one result, while on the integrated Intel HD 4000, I get another. The kernel is

```
__kernel void Chmv_(__global float2 *H, const float alpha, __global float2 *vec, 
                const int off/*in number of elements*/,
                __local float2 *vw,
                __global float2 *vout) 
{
int gidx=get_global_id(0);
int gidy=get_global_id(1);
int gs=get_global_size(0);

    vout[gidx].x += alpha*(H[gidx+gidy*gs].x*vec[gidy].x-H[gidx+gidy*gs].y*vec[gidy].y);
    vout[gidx].y += alpha*(H[gidx+gidy*gs].y*vec[gidy].x+H[gidx+gidy*gs].x*vec[gidy].y);

}
```

For tests, I let the Matrix `H` be a 4x4 matrix, filled with (1.0f, 0.0f), while input vector `vec` is has x components (0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0), and y components 0. `alpha` is set to 2.0f. So, I should have (12, 12, 12, 12) as x output, and I do, if I use CPU. NVIDIA gives me 6.0, while Intel gives me 4.0.

Now, closer inspection showed me that if the input vector is (0,1,2,0), NVIDIA gives me 0 as answer, and if it is (0,1,0,3), Intel gives 0 as well. By the way, changing `vec[gidy]` for `vec[gidx]` gives me just the vector doubled. From these, it seems to me that the kernel is executing well only in one dimension, x, while having only one value for `get_global_id(1)`, which is clearly not ok.

I will add the test function which is calling this kernel inspection. Now, anyone has any idea of what can be going on?

```
void _test_(){
cl_mem mat,vec, out;
size_t gs[2]={4,4};
size_t ls[2]={1,4};
size_t cpuws[2]={1,1};
cl_float2 *A=(cl_float2*)calloc(gs[0]*gs[0], sizeof(cl_float2));
cl_float2 *v=(cl_float2*)calloc(gs[0], sizeof(cl_float2));
cl_float2 *w=(cl_float2*)calloc(gs[0], sizeof(cl_float2));
int i;

for (i=0; i<gs[0]; i++) {
    A[i*gs[0]].x=1.0;
    A[i*gs[0]+1].x= 1.0;//(i<ls-1)? 1.0f:0.0f;
    A[i*gs[0]+2].x=1.0;
    A[i*gs[0]+3].x=1.0;
    v[i].x=  (float)i;
    printf("%d %f %f %f %f\n%v2f\n",i, A[i*gs[0]].x, A[i*gs[0]+1].x, A[i*gs[0]+2].x, A[i*gs[0]+3].x, v[i]);
}
v[2].x=0.0f; //<--- set individually for debug

mat = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, gs[0]*gs[0]*sizeof(cl_float2), NULL, NULL);
vec = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, gs[0]*sizeof(cl_float2), NULL, NULL);
out = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, gs[0]*sizeof(cl_float2), NULL, NULL);

error = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, mat, CL_TRUE, 0, gs[0]*gs[0]*sizeof(cl_float2), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
error = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, vec, CL_TRUE, 0, gs[0]*sizeof(cl_float2), v, 0, NULL, NULL);
error = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, out, CL_TRUE, 0, gs[0]*sizeof(cl_float2), w, 0, NULL, NULL);

int offset=0;
float alpha=2.0;
error  = clSetKernelArg(Chmv_, 0, sizeof(cl_mem),&mat);
error |= clSetKernelArg(Chmv_, 1, sizeof(float), &alpha);
error |= clSetKernelArg(Chmv_, 2, sizeof(cl_mem),&vec);
error |= clSetKernelArg(Chmv_, 3, sizeof(int), &offset);
error |= clSetKernelArg(Chmv_, 4, gs[0]*sizeof(cl_float2), NULL);
error |= clSetKernelArg(Chmv_, 5, sizeof(cl_mem), &out);
assert(error == CL_SUCCESS);

error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, Chmv_, 2, NULL, gs, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);

error = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, out, CL_TRUE, 0, gs[0]*sizeof(cl_float2), w, 0, NULL, NULL);
clFinish(queue);

for (i=0; i<gs[0]; i++) {
    printf("%f %f\n", w[i].x, w[i].y);

}

clReleaseMemObject(mat);
clReleaseMemObject(vec);
clReleaseMemObject(out);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing a typical problem of a multithreaded unsafe access to a common memory zone. (`vout`)

You have to think that all of the work-items will run concurrently. This means, they will read and write memory in any order.

When you execute in CPU, the problem does not show up since the execution is serially done by the HW.
However in the GPU, some work items read the memory of `vout`, increment it and write it. But others do also read the memory of `vout` before the new value is written by the previous work items.

Probably all your work items are running in parallel since your kernel size is small, that's why you only see one of them adding to the final result.

This is a typical parallel reduction problem. You can google it for more details. What you need to achieve is sync all the threads when accesing `vout`, either by an `atomic_add()` (slow) or by a proper reduction (hard to code). You can check this guide, it is for CUDA but is more or less the same basic idea : [Reduction Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf)

Comment: I see. I thought it would simply lead to a memory bank conflict, slowing down the kernel at first, but GPU seems to work differently then I thought, with all the threads/work_items reading the same "old value" and writing their own later. Never had it with MPI or OpenMP before (well, they are easier to handle in many ways). Actually, reduction is what I wanted since the beginning, and your link helped my whole job from now on. Thanks a lot!